# Suggestions for an initializer

Tags: java, initializer

I have created a document store class using Java which is internally backed by a hashmap ..        To intialise this document store I load a set of keys from config file ..
what would be the best way to assign an initial value ? right now I am using a BLANK .. does this make sense ? any better suggestions ?? 
  private static final String BLANK = "BLANK";
The document store accepts (String,String) as key,value

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's a good solution enough. May be you will need to guard it with some special symbols, e. g., "__BLANK__" or "@@BLANK@@".

Answer (score 1):

I would say that is a good way (provided no valid values will ever be `BLANK`) instead of the null because for performance it is better to do a `map.get("Key")` and test that against `null` than to test with the `containsKey("Key")`.  The `get` will return null if the key does not exist but if you use null as the value then you would not know if it exists or not since in both cases null will be returned.

Hope that is clear...
- Dave